# EF-generated SQL and properties mapping/projection

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to reuse the SQL generated by EntityFramework 6 as a sub-select in a manually created SQL statement. For example, the following query:

```
dbContext.Users
     .GroupBy(u => u.Email)
     .Select(g => new {Email = u.Key, Name = g.Max(u1 => u1.Name)})
     .ToString()
```

Results in following SQL:

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[GroupBy1].[K1] AS [Email], 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Email] AS [K1], 
    MAX([Extent1].[Name]) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
    GROUP BY [Extent1].[Email]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Note that list of the fields in select do not match the datatype returned by the query (there is a C1, C2 which are not in the anonymous type of {Email, Name}). Is there any way to figure out that mapping by looking at the query properties/etc? Then I'll be able to refer to those properties in the outer SQL statement.

Comment: Doing this sounds a little risky as the SQL query is generated dynamically, and there's no guarantee that it always be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off hand coding it.  Here's a full example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Users (Email varchar(200), Name varchar(200))

INSERT INTO #Users (Email, Name) VALUES ('vold@stack.com', 'Vololdymyr 1')
INSERT INTO #Users (Email, Name) VALUES ('vold@stack.com', 'Vololdymyr 2')

SELECT u.Email, MAX(u.Name) As Name FROM #Users u GROUP BY Email

DROP TABLE #Users
```

The results are:

```
Email               Name
---------------------------------
vold@stack.com      Vololdymyr 2
```

Comment: Thank you, though I already have hand-coded SQL and was looking for ways to leverage linq/VS intellisense and compile-time checks when writing my queries.

Comment: Ah, OK. I understand what you're doing now.  Thanks for explaining!